# Minimizing $\sqrt{(4\cos^3(x)-4\cos(x)+2)^2+(2\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x))^2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

I need to find minimum value of $\sqrt{(4\cos^3(x)-4\cos(x)+2)^2+(2\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x))^2}$.

I initially though differentiating would be the best way to go but later I felt that it is becoming too lengthy.Is any detour possible using trigonometric manipulation?Or is there an easier way for this?

Comment: You can change all $\sin$ function into some polynomials of $\cos x$.

Comment: change of variables $t=\cos(x)$: $\sqrt{(4t^3-4t+2)^2+t^2(2-4(1-t^2))^2}$

Comment: Maybe Weierstrass substitution $t=\tan\frac x2$?

Comment: @hkmather802 Ouch..that looks scary :-D

Comment: @Ignat Okay looks promising.Trying.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%5Csqrt%7B(4%5Ccos%5E3(x)-4%5Ccos(x)%2B2)%5E2%2B(2%5Csin(x)-4%5Csin%5E3(x))%5E2%7D

Comment: Of course, $\sqrt{\;f(x)\;}$ is minimized when $f(x)$ is minimized, so you can ignore the square root altogether. Expanding the trig expression and simplifying gives $$4 \left(\;2 - 4\cos x - \cos^2 x + 4 \cos^3 x\;\right)$$ where you can ignore the multiplied $4$ and make the substitution $u := \cos x$ to get a polynomial that's easily minimized with the help of differentiation.

Comment: @Blue Thanks a lot.I understood it.Some terms actually cancelled out :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Using the trigonometric identities for double and triple angles, you should find that 
$${(4\cos^3(x)-4\cos(x)+2)^2+(2\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x))^2}=-4 \cos (x)-2 \cos (2 x)+4 \cos (3 x)+6$$ Reuse the trig identities for $\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(3x)$ to get a simple polynomial in $\cos(x)$ (just as @Blue commented).

On the other hand, you want to minimize $$g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}\implies g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{2 \sqrt{f(x)}}$$ and since you want $g'(x)=0$, consider $f'(x)=0$.